Azure Web App (Linux) "run from package" not recognising .NET 8 app or able to find startup .dll
I'm deploying to an Azure Web App using an Azure DevOps pipeline.
My pipeline includes the steps:
 - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Prepare bundle'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: ArchiveFiles@2
    inputs:
      rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/drop'
      includeRootFolder: false
      archiveType: 'zip'
      archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app.zip'

   - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
     inputs:
      ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
      azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
      WebAppName: '$(appName)'
      packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app.zip'
      appType: 'webAppLinux'
      DeploymentType: 'runFromZip'
    displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'

My deploy succeeds and the appropriate files seem to be in the appropriate places. However, my app is not served and the logs show these errors:
2024-06-08T17:51:10.456139654Z: [INFO]  DotNet Runtime 8.0WARNING: Unable to find the startup DLL name. Could not find any files with extension '.runtimeconfig.json'
2024-06-08T17:51:10.477669204Z: [INFO]  Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2024-06-08T17:51:10.622328989Z: [INFO]  Trying to find the startup DLL name...
2024-06-08T17:51:10.624377013Z: [INFO]  Running the default app using command: dotnet "/defaulthome/hostingstart/hostingstart.dll"
2024-06-08T17:51:13.009364109Z: [INFO]  Hosting environment: Staging
2024-06-08T17:51:13.009405709Z: [INFO]  Content root path: /defaulthome/hostingstart/

If I unzip the archive in the wwwroot folder, my application is served, which tells me the contents and structure of the folder are fine. But I understand I should be able to serve the application directly from the zip file without extracting it. I've also made sure WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to '1' but I believe that var is only for Windows anyway.

Try adding Startupcommand in your Azure App service as dotnet .dll.Check this image.

@AsleshaKantamsetti thanks, but this didn't work - I didn't really expect it to because the app is inside a .zip file. "RunFromPackage" should be mounting the entire .zip.

@BlairHarper, As mentioned in my answer below, the the "dotnet publish" command will automatically archive the build artifact files of the web app to be a ZIP file (AppName.zip) into the specified output directory.  You do not need an extra ArchiveFiles@2 task

For the web app, the "dotnet publish" command will automatically archive the build artifact files to be a ZIP file (AppName.zip) into the specified output directory. So, you do not need an extra ArchiveFiles@2 task to archive the output file again, otherwise it will archive the output ZIP file into another ZIP file.
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Prepare bundle'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
    WebAppName: '$(appName)'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.zip'
    appType: 'webAppLinux'
    DeploymentType: 'runFromZip'

By this way, the web app deploy task will automatically unzip the ZIP file and push all the build artifact files into the wwwroot folder on your Azure app service.

